# Caster wheel inserts and tube failiure on bar cart

Tags: repair, furniture, metal

recently received a new bar cart as a gift, and assembled and loaded it up. Unfortunately as I was pushing it along my carpet the tubes the inserts were in bent and the inserts fell out. How should I go about repairing this? Should I just fill the tube with epoxy and put the inserts back in?
Thanks for reading, images of issue are attached.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Epoxy and the inserts probably will never come out if you need to replace them.  Would drill a hole though tube and insert and use a bolt to hold it on.

Comment: "New bar cart" should have _some_ sort of warranty. Contact the gift giver for purchase info, then the seller or manufacturer for a warranty claim. Shouldn't fall apart on the first use. The fewer times people complain about shoddy workmanship, the more of it we'll _all_ get.

Comment: I don't see any bent metal there.  This looks more like a case of a loose fit between caster post and cart tube.   Cheap stuff is cheap.   You may well have to deal with poor rotation of the wheels, which could have left a wheel rotated with respect to the direction you were moving, leading to massive drag on the carpet, leading to this mess.

Answer (score 1):

Get a piece of hardwood that fits snugly in the square tube. The tighter, the better. You might have to get a piece that is oversized and trim it down, or round the corners.

You also want it to be as long as possible. I see that the tube has a bolt through it. I would probably take that out and extend the wood beyond it, then drill a hole for the bolt to be reinstalled.

Finally, drill a hole in to the bottom and screw in the caster.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it would hold pretty solid for sure. Should I glue the piece of wood into place inside the tube?

Comment: I don't think it will be necessary to glue it. The force of the tight fitting wood will probably be enough. And if you out the bolt through it, all the better.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that square tube and its thickness, I would be looking to drill both front tubes to take a long axle and fit better wheels at the front then use the rear casters for steering.